# History search failing to execute in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I am in the process of writing an extension for Chrome to display the users 3 most visited sites. (Yes, I am aware that the "New Tab" page already does this) However, whenever I try to query the users history then it seems like the entire script shuts down.

My manifest files does contain:

```
{
    "name": "Most Visited Sites Test",
    "description": "Show your most visited sites",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background_page": "background.html",
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "http://localhost/*"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "history",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "notifications"
    ],
    "icons": {"128": "icon.png" },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["contentscript.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

So I believe this ought to give my background page the ability to use the history. However, my background page contains:

```
function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    alert("Call 1");

    var oneWeekAgo = //Code for getting last weeks date;
    chrome.history.search({
    'text': '',
    'startTime': oneWeekAgo
    },
    function(historyItems)
    {
        // Do stuff...
    });

   alert("Call 2");
};
```

The request is sent from my contentscript.js

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest("foo");
```

When run, "Call 1" is shown but then nothing is done with the history and "Call 2" is never shown. What might be causing this? I apologize if this is a simple problem but this is my first attempt at a legitimate Chrome extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening console to see if there any errors is the first thing I always do (go to the Extensions tab and click on "background.html").

Your history call is correct, so maybe your last week calculation isn't? This is what works for me:

```
chrome.history.search({text: "", startTime:(new Date()).getTime()-7*24*3600*1000}, function(items) {
    console.log(items);
});
```

Comment: That's strange. I checked the console and it's telling me

    (Error: You do not have permission to use 'history.search'. Be sure to declare in your manifest what permissions you need.)
Specifically, I have

    ("permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "history",
  "unlimitedStorage",
  "notifications"
 ])

Comment: @Mike Are you running this from a background.html, not a content script?

Comment: The content script sends a request to the background.html then the background.html executes the chrome.history.search.

Comment: @Mike Then there is something wrong with your manifest, if you post it I can take a look.

Comment: Being that there's no support for line-breaks in comments I'll give you this [link](http://pastebin.com/z4TUsAhN) I appreciate you taking the time to look this over.

Comment: @Mike I copied your manifest into the question, if you don't mind. The problem is that apps are allowed to request only "background", "geolocation", "notifications", and "unlimitedStorage" permissions. "History" is available only to extensions. You can read about it here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html

Comment: That's fine. Oh wow, I don't know how I missed that, that clears up everything. Thanks :)